# How to set a type of a function's prop after destructuring?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a problem with setting props type.

```
export default function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...rest}) {
  const {currentUser} = useAuth();

      return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={(props) => {
            return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
          }}
        ></Route>
      );
    }
```

I've made a simple Private Route, which in the component is renamed to Component with capital C. But I also want to set the type of this component to a React Component, how can I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide the type of the object that you're destructuring. For instance, if `Component` is `FunctionComponent<PropsType> | ComponentClass<PropsType>`, the overall object might be `{component: FunctionComponent<PropsType> | ComponentClass<PropsType>}`:

```typescript
export default function PrivateRoute<PropsType extends object>(
    {component: Component, ...rest}: {component: FunctionComponent<PropsType> | ComponentClass<PropsType>}
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  destructuring                    type of object
) {
    const {currentUser} = useAuth();
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props: PropsType) => {
// Note −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^
                return currentUser
                    ? <Component {...props} />
                    : <Redirect to="/" />;
            }}
        ></Route>
    );
}
```

There I've used  a type parameter (`PropsType`), but if you have a concrete type you can use instead, use that.